# How to show form while macro doesn't execute?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I'm working with the Microsoft Access database. I export several queries to an Excel template through a subset of Access (using Microsoft Excel Object library).

Now, the template opens on worksheet start-up, and begins (from Access) copying data from other sheets.

Here's my problem. I want a form to show while Access copies data to my workbook. I don't know how to do this.

After data is finished copying to my workbook, I have a first macro. Executing this shows the form. But I would like to show the form during the copy.

Summarizing,

1. Access opens template.
2. Access begins to copy queries
3. My problem... I see the worksheet, but not my form.
4. Access finished to copy data
5. From Access I execute My Macro
6. I see my form while My Macro is running
7. My form hides and I have my worksheet ready.

Code to export data (Access):

```
Public Sub CreateExcelInfo()
'Set reference to Microsoft Excel Object library
'Set reference to Microsoft ActiveX DataObject 2.x

Dim oExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim WB As New Excel.Workbook
Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rng As Excel.Range
Dim objRs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim objRs2 As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim objRs3 As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim objRs4 As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim objRs5 As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim objRs6 As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim objRs7 As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sSQL, sSQL2, sSQL3, sSQL4, sSQL5, sSQL6 As Variant
Dim sSQL7 As String
MsgBox ("Este proceso puede tardar unos minutos." & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "Por favor abstengase de realizar tareas en el equipo hasta ver el mensaje de finalizado."), vbOKOnly
sFileNameTemplate = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\templates\Informes.xlsm"
sSQL = "SELECT [VALOR POR TRABAJO EXPORTAR].*FROM [VALOR POR TRABAJO EXPORTAR] " 'This has to be the name of the query your report is using to display data
sSQL2 = "SELECT [DETALLE REPROCESOS Y GARANTÍAS PARA EXPORTAR].*FROM [DETALLE REPROCESOS Y GARANTÍAS PARA EXPORTAR] " 'This has to be the name of the query your report is using to display data
sSQL3 = "SELECT [DETALLE HISTORICO PARA EXPORTAR].*FROM [DETALLE HISTORICO PARA EXPORTAR] " 'This has to be the name of the query your report is using to display data
sSQL4 = "SELECT Clientes.NombreCompañía FROM EMPRESA LEFT JOIN Clientes ON EMPRESA.Empresa = Clientes.IdCliente " 'Export the name register in table EMPRESA
sSQL5 = "SELECT [COMENTARIOS ÚLTIMO CIERRE].TipoComentarioInventario, [COMENTARIOS ÚLTIMO CIERRE].Comentario FROM [COMENTARIOS ÚLTIMO CIERRE] " 'Export comments last inventory
sSQL6 = "SELECT [_Indicadores_Pintura].Indicador, HISTORY.Valor FROM (HISTORY RIGHT JOIN [ÚLTIMO INVENTARIO DE CIERRE] ON HISTORY.IdInventario = [ÚLTIMO INVENTARIO DE CIERRE].ÚltimoDeIdInventario) LEFT JOIN _Indicadores_Pintura ON HISTORY.IdIndicador = [_Indicadores_Pintura].IdIndicador WHERE (((HISTORY.IdIndicador)=1 Or (HISTORY.IdIndicador)=2 Or (HISTORY.IdIndicador)=8 Or (HISTORY.IdIndicador)=9 Or (HISTORY.IdIndicador)=10 Or (HISTORY.IdIndicador)=12 Or (HISTORY.IdIndicador)=13 Or (HISTORY.IdIndicador)=14 Or (HISTORY.IdIndicador)=15 Or (HISTORY.IdIndicador)=16 Or (HISTORY.IdIndicador)=17 Or (HISTORY.IdIndicador)=18 Or (HISTORY.IdIndicador)=19 Or (HISTORY.IdIndicador)=20 Or (HISTORY.IdIndicador)=21)) " 'Export data of last inventory
sSQL7 = "SELECT INVENTARIOS.Observaciones FROM [ÚLTIMO INVENTARIO DE CIERRE] LEFT JOIN INVENTARIOS ON [ÚLTIMO INVENTARIO DE CIERRE].ÚltimoDeIdInventario = INVENTARIOS.IdInventario " 'Export inventory name
With oExcel
.Visible = True
            Set WB = .Workbooks.Add(sFileNameTemplate)
                With WB
                     Set WS = WB.Worksheets("DetalleTrabajos")
                     With WS
                              objRs.Open sSQL, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly
                              Set rng = .Range("A2")
                              rng.CopyFromRecordset objRs
                              objRs.Close
                     End With
                End With
                With WB
                     Set WS = WB.Worksheets("DetalleReprocesosYGarantías")
                     With WS
                              objRs2.Open sSQL2, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly
                              Set rng = .Range("A2")
                              rng.CopyFromRecordset objRs2
                              objRs2.Close
                     End With
                End With
                With WB
                     Set WS = WB.Worksheets("DetalleHistorico")
                     With WS
                              objRs3.Open sSQL3, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly
                              Set rng = .Range("A2")
                              rng.CopyFromRecordset objRs3
                              objRs3.Close
                     End With
                End With
                With WB
                     Set WS = WB.Worksheets("Indicadores Globales")
                     With WS
                              objRs7.Open sSQL7, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly
                              Set rng = .Range("C7")
                              rng.CopyFromRecordset objRs7
                              objRs7.Close
                     End With
                     With WS
                              objRs6.Open sSQL6, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly
                              Set rng = .Range("H24")
                              rng.CopyFromRecordset objRs6
                              objRs6.Close
                     End With

                     With WS
                              objRs5.Open sSQL5, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly
                              Set rng = .Range("B24")
                              rng.CopyFromRecordset objRs5
                              objRs5.Close
                     End With
                End With
                With WB
                     Set WS = WB.Worksheets("Parámetros")
                     With WS
                              objRs4.Open sSQL4, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly
                              Set rng = .Range("B10")
                              rng.CopyFromRecordset objRs4
                              objRs4.Close
                     End With
                End With
                With WB
                     Set WS = WB.Worksheets("Inicio")
                     With WS
                        oExcel.Run "Bienvenidos"
                     End With
                End With

End With

Set objRs = Nothing
Set objRs2 = Nothing
Set objRs3 = Nothing
Set objRs4 = Nothing
Set objRs5 = Nothing
Set objRs6 = Nothing
Set objRs7 = Nothing

MsgBox ("!El informe se ha realizado correctamente!"), vbOKOnly

End Sub
```

MyCode when the BookOpen:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
End Sub
```

In My Form:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose _
(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Call ActualizarCeldas
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Please check your code before posting it! This would not compile! You have 9 `With` and just 6 `End With`. Also there are `If` without `End If` and `End If` without `If`...

Comment: Yes! I corrected. Paste all the code again! This compiles!

Comment: Is it the complete code?

Comment: Yes. Or at least those involved.

Comment: I have corrected your code for better visibility. Please try running it and see if everything remains the same?

Comment: Also you mentioned that you fixed something related to not using `objConn`. Do you mind correcting the code that we see here to reflect your changes?

Comment: Done. You can see now. Run right!

Comment: You removed everything I made before... **(1)** The code is again full with `With WB` which are useless and **(2)** indentation is poor. **(3)** Also, `Dim sSQL, sSQL2, sSQL3, sSQL4, sSQL5, sSQL6, sSQL7 As String` only makes `sSQL7` string. All others are of `Variant` type!

Comment: Sorry! I read that you made some changes but never upgrade my browser it. Really I could not see the changes that you mention... It is impossible to reverse my change?

Comment: Analyse [this](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31063240/revisions).

Comment: Fixed! I use this in my db and worked. Also edit here with your changes!

Comment: Now. Aftrt correcting and improving the code. Could you help me with my problem of form..?

Comment: No you did not do any changes that I suggested in the Edit that I made. However, in order to help you, you should show us where and how do you open your form. From your 5th step I assume that the line which opens your form is in "My Macro". You did not provide us the code in "My Macro", so we don't see where you open your form! Without having that code we cannot help you. If in that code you have some `Userform.Show`, just use it earlier, like [@ChipsLetten explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31063240/how-to-show-form-while-macro-doesnt-execute?noredirect=1#31070998)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show a userform in Excel but keep other code running, you need to show the form in non-modal style.

```
userFormName.Show False
```

Be careful if your userform has buttons or other controls for the user to click because, if they click, the code that runs might interfere/interrupt the other code.

I couldn't see in your existing code where the form currently gets shown.

Comment: Very thanks. I used the option proposed for @ChipsLetten's. However, ZygD suggestions were also very useful.